# Pass name containing & to next page using query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

This is my passing code in first page

```
protected void btnsbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact(txtfrmdate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
    DateTime b = DateTime.ParseExact(txttodate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
    string c = txtCustomerName.Text.ToString();

    Response.Redirect("frmRptSalesBillWiseView.aspx?drop=" + a + "&radio=" + b + "&CustName=" + c + "");
}
```

When I pass the name "`A & A CONTAINER CONVERSIONS`" to the next page I'm getting only "`A`".

Code on the second page:

```
custname1 = Request.QueryString["CustName"];
```

Comment: You can try to HTML Encode the URL before sending to preserve the & character in your value.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using Server.UrlEncode()

Response.Redirect("frmRptSalesBillWiseView.aspx?drop=" + a + "&radio=" + b + "&CustName=" + Server.UrlEncode(c) + "");
}

Answer (score 0):

you should `Encode` url. Try using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. like:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("A & A CONTAINER CONVERSIONS")
```

Comment: If i giving like this   Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("frmRptSalesBillWiseView.aspx?drop=" + a + "&radio=" + b + "&CustName=" + c + ""));     i'm getting error as HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found

Comment: @ASP.NET dont encode the whole url. you can only encode the query string.

Answer (score 0):

As the name "A & A CONTAINER CONVERSIONS" contains special character "&" (Ampersand), that has a special meaning in the query string.

& is used to separate multiple values in the query string.
For example : `?a=123&b=hi&c=bye`

In the above example the query string has 3 values Separated by "&" only.

So, You have to encode the name using [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)